# How would I embed a ustream video into an iframe?

Tags: embedly

I would like to embed ustream using embedly, but it isn't allowing me to do so. Is it possible to embed a ustream?

Answer (score 0):

If it is your ustream simply go to your dashboard and click embed.  The code provided just needs to be pated into your html.

If it is not your code (and the user has not locked the stream to their page or site) then simply use ustream.tv/embed/(channel id without parentheses)